# How to add facebook like in multiple blog post like your index file in wordpress?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i would like to implement or add a facebook like button in my wordpress blog. But this time, i want it on my index file or in a multiple blog post. The problem is when I copy pasted what facebook is generating for me is it only "likes" my domain name or my index file, not the blog post which is suppose to be liked.

What should i do to correctly add the facebook like button to work?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple actually. You still need the codes for Facebook Like button but you have to modify it. Add the value `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` in the url to like and that's it.

Just make sure that you have the correct meta tags such as title and description so that facebook can successfully scrape your blogpost.